# What painting/drawing software could possibly create these YouTube videos?

Tags: video

I came across these videos and I can't tell how they were created. Photoshop? After Effects? Something else? The brush used in the video - anyone recognize?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGTrzTKzKmk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayzVNkIJsk8

Comment: Illustrator is generally the go-to for producing realistic-looking brushstrokes like that.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the artifacts showing in the video, the images were created in complete form using any number of graphics editing software. I think the video was then created by erasing components of the work and playing it in reverse.

You can observe branches from the main body appearing when the "brush" had not yet traveled in that region.

It is easier to erase smoothly a circular segment while recording than it is to freehand such a segment.

Comment: Erase makes sense. But I don't see the brush, that's interesting. Wish I could find such software.

Comment: I use snagit for screen captures and it allows to have the cursor vanish during the recording. I've only now tested it to determine if that also refers to the cursor of an image editor. In this case, Paint Shop Pro displays a cursor even when turned off.

Comment: The final render made from reverse of screen cast of graphic tablet  drawing